# Prove $a \in\mathbb I, b \in \mathbb I \implies a^b \in \mathbb I$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mathbb I$ be the set of Irrational numbers and  $\mathbb Q$ be the set of Rational numbers. Show $a \in \mathbb I, b \in\mathbb I\implies a^b \in\mathbb I$

Using a counter example I can prove this:

$a = \sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$ 
$b = \sqrt{2}$

$\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}\times\sqrt{2}}  = 2$

since $Q \subset I$ we can say $2 \in I$

is this correct? Or is there a rigorous proof? Thanks. :)

Comment: It might be good to say what $Q$ and $I$ are.

Comment: Is $I$ the set of irrational numbers?

Comment: If $I$ are the integers and $Q$ are the rationals, then is it NOT true that $Q \subset I$.

Comment: Oops I'm sorry. Yea yeah :) $Q$ is the set or rational and $ I $ is the set of Irrational!

Comment: for starters, $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}\cdot \sqrt{2} \neq 2$ [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%282%29^sqrt%282%29+*+sqrt%282%29).  Perhaps you should try looking at logarithms and [related numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29).  Also, with $\mathbb{Q}$ as the *rational numbers*, and $\mathbb{R}$ as the *real numbers*, the *irrational numbers* are often defined as $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$.  In particular, that means that $\mathbb{Q}\cap I = \emptyset$ and that $\mathbb{Q}\not\subset I$

Comment: I don't even know what you want to show.... You want to show that's true for all $a, b\in I$?

Comment: Still I can't type latex properly. :/ If you can notice, I've taken $a & b$ so that I can replace with $a^b$. (root two) ^ ((ROOT TWO) x (root two)).

Comment: Ah, fair enough.  I was reading John's edit, which showed $a\times b$.  Yes, then that counterexample works fine.  Your conclusion needs to be fixed though to read "since $\mathbb{Q}\cap I = \emptyset$ and $2\in\mathbb{Q}$, we know that $2\not\in I$ and therefore ..."  Since you already have a correct counterexample, I'll just outright say the counterexample I hinted at:  $e$ and $\ln 2$, but $e^{\ln 2} = 2$ (same conclusion)

Comment: This looks like an attempt to  write down  the standard cute proof that there exist irrationals $a$ and $b$ such that $a^b$ is rational.  Quite a lot of rewriting is required.  It may be best to use a minimal number of mathematical symbols.

Comment: So @JMoravitz , That means this is a disprove of that statement?

Comment: Correct.  The statement is false.  If you *were* trying to prove the statement is true, then you would have a hard time (since we just showed it is false), and in particular **no** proof that a statement is **true** for *general numbers* can be done via example.

Comment: But @JMoravitz If I take $ b = \sqrt{3}$ then the result is an irrational number right? :/

Comment: @blogger there do exist irrational numbers which when raised to a particular irrational power remain irrational.  There also exist irrational numbers which when raised to a particular irrational power no longer remain irrational.  The point is that they are **"not closed under exponentiation"** (or multiplication or addition).  What is not true is that *every* irrational number raised to *any* irrational power yields an *irrational* result.  Compare this to the situation where you take a natural number raised to the power of a natural number (which will always yield a natural number).

Comment: And I've assumed $\mathbb Q$ is a sub set of $\mathbb I$ where I went wrong.

Comment: @JMoravitz: $e^{\ln 2}$ is a good example, but it requires one to prove that $e$ is irrational (not hard) and so is $\ln 2$ (harder). An example in which the irrationality proofs are easier is $a=\sqrt{2}$ and $b=2\log_2(3)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is a sketch of the proof that there **are** irrational numbers $a,\,b$ such that $a^b$ is rational - that is, assuming that you accept the law of excluded middle (that a proposition must be either true or false) so this is not a proof to an intuitionist: but I digress.

You argue as follows. Let $a = \sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$. Now either $a$ is rational or it is not (this is where an intuitionist would reject the proof).

If it is irrational, then raising to the irrational power $\sqrt{2}$ yields a rational number, to wit $2$. Therefore we have an example of an irrational ($a$) to an irrational power that is rational.

On the other hand, if $a$ is not irrational, it is rational, and so $a$ itself stands as an example of an irrational ($\sqrt{2}$) raised to a irrational power ($\sqrt{2}$) which yields a rational result.

Either way, we have a counterexample. Curiously, there is no way from this proof to tell which one is the counterexample: we simply know we have one, disproving the proposition.

Comment: But if I take $ b= \sqrt{3}$ then the result is an irrational number right? :/

Comment: @blogger correct, it will be irrational, but that is irrelevant.  All we needed was one counter example to show that the statement was false.  Something that is not *always true* is false.  Note, the difference between "not *always true*" and "*always not* true".

Comment: @JMoravitz Now I get it. If we are prompted to prove something and if we can get a single tiny counter example, then it is proved wrong! :D Math is devilishly cool :D thanks all. I've learnt a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This statement is **not** true, because if $\sqrt2^\sqrt2$ is rational, you can choose $a=b=\sqrt2$ and if not, by choosing $a=\sqrt2^\sqrt2$ and $b=\sqrt2$ we get $a^b=2$ we get the counter-example.

Comment: +1: Who is that (presumably) mathematician on your user page?

Comment: Peter Gustav Lejeune Dirichlet...I like him more than any other mathematician...

Comment: Thanks: I've just realized I've never seen a picture of Dirichlet.

Answer (score -1):

To show that
$a^b \in I$,
you have to use induction.

Assumptions:
$I$ means the natural (positive) integers,
$a \in I$ and $b \in I$.

Needed results:
Inductive definition of exponentiation
and the product of
two elements of $I$
is also in $I$.

Base step:
For $b=1$,
$a^1 = a \in I$.

Suppose true for $b$
(i.e., $a^b \in I$).
Then

$\begin{array}\\
a^{b+1}
&=a^b\cdot a
\quad\text{(by the inductive definition of exponentiation)}\\
&\in I
\quad\text{(because $a^b \in I, a \in I$, and product of elements in $I$ is in $I$)}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: would have been useful if $I$ were in fact integers or natural numbers.  Unfortunately, how would you go about doing induction on the irrational numbers?  What would that accomplish (especially since there are obvious counter examples to the question of if irrationals are closed under exponentiation).

Comment: @JMoravitz Can't we use Induction for Irrational numbers?

Comment: What does "the next irrational number" mean? You need the concept of "next number" to do induction.

Comment: Precisely my point @marty.  The OP has made it clear that $I$ is the set of irrationals, not the set of naturals or integers.  See the fourth comment on the original post above, and also note that $\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2}$ are not integers yet he wanted each of those to be in $I$ (which was clear before any edit or additional clarification).

Comment: I entered my answer before the OP clarified (i.e., changed) the problem.

Comment: I'm going to use this answer as a cautionary tale for others. Be sure to fully understand what the OP is asking before answering a question, lest your answer be completely wrong like in this case.

Comment: Clearly, correctness is, in this case, a function of time. Oh well, as Clifford Simak said as the last line of one of his stories, "Time is the simplest thing."

Comment: What was written in the OP was unintelligible, for example the assertion that since $Q\subset I$ we can say $2\in I$. From the title it was  quite reasonable to interpret $I$ as the set of (positive?) integers.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Our lecturers use $\mathbb I$ for Irrational numbers and $\mathbb Z$ for Integers $\mathbb Z+$ for positive Integers. I thought it is the same everywhere and even the paper states the question as I've typed it and didn't bothered to mention it additionally :/ Sorry for the confusion. Anyway we got the answer and a hell lot of a clarification :D Thanks all for sharing their knowledge with me!!!